# How to calculate this integral tends to zero?

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

I've posted this before, but I was unable to solve this...

Setting :

- U is a bounded Lipschitz domain in the complex plane
- Consider the following classical Dirichlet problem for the Laplace operator:
  $$\begin{align}
  \Delta{}u&=0\ \  in\ \ \  U\\
  u&=f\ \ \partial U.\end{align}
  $$
- $F(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|$ denotes the fundamental solution for the Laplacian in the complex plane.
- For $x\in{}U$, $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$ denotes the usual ball centered at x with raidus $\epsilon>0$. $U_\epsilon{}=U\backslash B(x,\epsilon)$.

So what I want to get is the following
$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{\partial{}B(x,\epsilon)}F(x-y)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\nu}}(y)d\sigma(y)=\int\limits_{\partial{}B(x,\epsilon)}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\nu}}(y)d\sigma(y)
\end{align}$$
tends to zero as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$. The author says I can derive this by using the explicit formula for $F$, but I don't know how to. Please help me with this.

The book is Classical and Multilinear Harmonica Analysis Volume 2, Muscalu, Schlag.

Comment: Note that $y\mapsto F(x-y)$ is constant on $\partial B(x,\epsilon)$, and is equal to $-1/2\pi\log(\epsilon)$. Hence, you can factor it, and you need a final inequality of the form $|\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}\partial u/\partial\nu|\leq c\epsilon$, but I can't tell much about that without more information on $u$.